# SQL Consolidate Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get all the strings found under a column and build a string combination based on them.

To illustrate:

#### Objects (o)

```
id  group_id   name        type                     
----------------------------------------------------
1   100        Computer    Computer - Standard
2   100        Telephone   Telephone - Modified
3   100        Table       Table - Standard - Deal
```

As you can see under `type` I'm looking for the words `Standard` and `Modified` (there are others but I only show 2 for simplicity) and want to build a string combining these words once and have the result as a column for each row.

I can get the keyword for each row using `CASE` and `LIKE` and assign that word as the value of the column like these:

```
id  group_id   name        type                     consolidated
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   100        Computer    Computer - Standard      Standard
2   100        Telephone   Telephone - Modified     Modified
3   100        Table       Table - Standard - Deal  Standard
```

But that's not really what I wanted. I just don't know how to join them like I want to.

```
id  group_id   name        type                     consolidated
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   100        Computer    Computer - Standard      Standard / Modified
2   100        Telephone   Telephone - Modified     Standard / Modified
3   100        Table       Table - Standard - Deal  Standard / Modified
```

#### Edit

Sorry I forgot to add my current query.

```
SELECT o.id, o.group_id, o.name, o.type,
CASE
  WHEN o.type LIKE '%Standard%' THEN 'Standard'
  WHEN o.type LIKE '%Modified%' THEN 'Modified'
  ELSE ''
END AS consolidated
FROM objects o
WHERE o.group_id = 100
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - are you asking how to concatenate a string from two other columns?

Comment: @wrschneider Not exactly, I want to concatenate specific words found under 1 column across multiple rows. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Will it always be limited to two values?

Comment: @shawnt00 Nope, there will be other values and I want to concatenate all of them together using `/`.

Comment: Look at `LISTAGG() OVER ()`

Comment: @shawnt00 That looks like what I need to concatenate the words using `/` but it shows the entire column. I just want specific words from a column not the entire data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH q as (
    SELECT o.id, o.group_id, o.name, o.type,
    CASE
        WHEN o.type LIKE '%Standard%' THEN 'Standard'
        WHEN o.type LIKE '%Modified%' THEN 'Modified'
        ELSE ''
    END AS lbl
    FROM objects o
    WHERE o.group_id = 100
)
SELECT
    id, group_id, name, type,
    (
      SELECT LISTAGG(lbl, ' / ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ??)
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT lbl FROM q) dc
    ) as consolidated
FROM q;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `FROM` keyword not found where expected. Also, what is `lbl`?

Comment: I got it working now, I just had to change your `lbl` to `consolidated`. Thanks!

Comment: `lbl` was just me renaming your column to avoid using `consolidated` twice. I missed one the first time around.